# How to add HTTP header in uwsgi logs

Tags: nginx, logging, http-headers, uwsgi

I have a `nginx` as proxy, and `uWSGI` as app server. And I want to add any http headers to uwsgi logs. I can add some `var.VAR_NAME` to logs.

By docs (http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/LogFormat.html):

> %(var.XXX) -> the content of request variable XXX (like var.PATH_INFO, available from
>   1.9.21)

But this worked only for `uwsgi_param` from nginx, not for `proxy_set_header` or smt. like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer in `uwsgi` github issues - https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1407#issuecomment-326605267 and updated the docs (http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/LogFormat.html):

> %(var.XXX) -> the content of request variable XXX (like var.PATH_INFO
>   or var.HTTP_X_MY_HEADER for headers from request, available from
>   1.9.21)